# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() FOR removing an element from a list

Tags: python, list

`images` is a dictionary below. `new` is a tuple with size of 2. `new[0]` is 1000 images. Each image is a raw of `784`. So, it is with a shape of `(1000,784)`.
`new[1]` is their labels. I mean `0` or `1`. It is np array of `int`

```
images = defaultdict(list)
new=data[0]

for image, label in zip(*new):
    images[label].append(image)

listImages=images[0]
r=[listImages[0],listImages[1],listImages[2]]
listImages.remove(r[1])
```

I am wondering why the below error comes up after calling `.remove()`:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: I am wondering what part of the code this error refers to.

Comment: @ScottHunter I guess it's the `.remove()` call.

Comment: The last line gives me error

Comment: Could you give us some sample data for `new`?

Comment: `new[0]` is 1000 images. Each image is a raw of `784`. So, it is with a shape of `(1000,784)`.
`new[1]` is their labels. I mean `0` or `1`. It is np array of `int`

Comment: That is a Numpy error/exception - I don't see an ndarray in this code.  When asking a question about an exception/error, please post the complete traceback- there are clues in it.

Comment: That error typically results when expecting a single boolean from a comparison on an ndarray. For example - ```if a == 5:``` where ```a``` is an ndarray.

Comment: Wondering it works if we first remove `r[0]` by `listImages.remove(r[0])`. However it does not work if we want to remove that of index 1 or 2 before 0

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not about the method .remove(), but the type difference between 'numpy.intXX' and 'int'.

When using tuple as the key of a dictionary, the types of the tuple entries are best to be 'int' rather than 'numpy.intXX'. I encounter the same error raised when examining the existence of a 'numpy.int32'-type entry composed tuple, which is directly derived from tuple(aNumpyArray).

To eliminate this error, I defined a function as

```
def safeTuple(inputList):
    return tuple(map(lambda x: int(x), inputList))
```

to make sure that the types of the entries are 'int'. Thus, I never encounter this error.

Hoping this helpful.